# ruby linting with vscode remote + docker

Tags: lint, vscode-remote

I've managed to set up [VSCode remote containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced) over SSH accessing my docker containers on the remote host (+ docker-compose).

One thing I can't work out however, is how to use extensions like ruby-rubocop (linter). I can install it on the remote SSH host, but it doesn't work, because my remote host doesn't directly run ruby. It's running inside one of my containers...

Is there a way to get it running inside a *container* on the remote host?